# ggplot with facets: Provide different width to dodge with each facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use position_dodge with facets in ggplot. The Problem is that the scale for each facet differs, so I would need to provide a different width to position_dodge for each facet. Is this possible?

As I also want to dodge geom_point(), automatic calculation of this width is neither possible.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.table(title= as.factor(c("car1", "car1", "car2", "car2", "car3") ), 
                   scenario=as.factor(c("normal", "high", "normal", "high", "normal")), 
                   price = c(1000,1000, 500,700,500), 
                   doors= c(2,2,4, 4,2) )
data.long <- melt(data, id.vars=c("title", "scenario") )
data.long[,y_value :=value/mean(value), by= .(variable) ]

#can this be used in position_dodge?
data.long[, width_dodge:=(max(value)-min(value))/10, by=variable]


ggplot(data.long ,aes(x=value, y=y_value, shape=scenario, fill=title))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=value-width_dodge,
                xmax=value+width_dodge,
                ymax=y_value , fill=title),
            ymin=0, position=position_dodge() )+
  scale_shape_manual(values=21:24)+
  #can position_dodge(width )  be different per facet?
  geom_point(aes(fill=title), colour="Black",position = position_dodge(width = 5) )+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: I just saw a question I asked some years before: [get scales/range of facets (scales='free')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898651/get-scales-range-of-facets-scales-free) .Maybe this provides a way to the answer...

Comment: Just a general question/ comment  - isn't the principal idea behind facetting that you have the same scales in each facet, for comparison? If you intend to do a multipanel figure I would suggest other packages such as the `patchwork` package (by @thomasp85), available at github

Comment: @Tjebo: I agree. But I want to do a comparison on both facets - in my original problem I normalize them to the same y_scale. Edited the example to make this clear. Beside that, there are also other reasons to compare with free scales - for example, comparing trends in different variables (although I know that  ggplot can be limited in this aspect...).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using the usual way: "Calculate outside ggplot". Could have thought about this earlier...

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.table(title= as.factor(c("car1", "car1", "car2", "car2", "car3") ), 
                   scenario=as.factor(c("normal", "high", "normal", "high", "normal")), 
                   price = c(1000,1000, 500,700,500), 
                   doors= c(2,2,4, 4,2) )
data.long <- melt(data, id.vars=c("title", "scenario") )
data.long[,y_value :=value/mean(value), by= .(variable) ]

#this can be used in value_dodgedx
data.long[, width_dodge:=(max(value)-min(value))/10, by=variable]
data.long[,`:=`( I_group=1:.N,
                 N_group=.N, 
                 group=.GRP,
                 #Here the actual dodging is done
                 value_dodgedx = value - ( (1:.N-0.5) - .N/2) *width_dodge ),
          , by=.(variable, value, y_value)]


#providing x=value_dodgedx instead of x=value
ggplot(data.long ,aes(x=value_dodgedx, y=y_value, shape=scenario, fill=title ))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=value_dodgedx-width_dodge/2,
                xmax=value_dodgedx+width_dodge/2,
                ymax=y_value , fill=title),
            ymin=0, position=position_dodge() )+
  scale_shape_manual(values=21:24)+
  geom_point(colour="Black")+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]